# How to parse a Vector List from a .txt File

Tags: c++

I have a project where I have to read a vector list from a .txt file and parse it. I have the vector list displaying on the screen but I do not know how to parse it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream vl;
    vl.open("PIXA.txt");
    char output[100];

    if (vl.is_open()) {
        while (!vl.eof()) {         
            vl >> output;
            cout << output;
        }
        vl >> output;
        cout << output;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    vl.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone help out with adding code so that I can parse this .txt file?

Here is what the .txt file looks like:

```
J
366 -1722   583
366   356  1783
866   789  1033
866 -1289  -167
366 -1722   583

J
-500 -1472   150
0 -1039  -600
0  1039   600
-500   606  1350
-500 -1472   150

J
366   356  1783
-500   606  1350
0  1039   600
866   789  1033
366   356  1783

J
366 -1722   583
866 -1289  -167
0 -1039  -600
-500 -1472   150
366 -1722   583
```

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: A list of 3x3 matrices. It doesn't paste right on here.

Comment: @DavidEdwardsJr. _"It doesn't paste right on here."_ Use the same format style as used for code. If you don't have a plain text file, you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: I do have a plain text file. I need to read from it. In the text file, i have 11 3x3 matrices to parse through.

Comment: Apologies guys. I've posted what the file looks like. Honestly I do not know where to start with the parsing. I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction in regards to that.

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but I was expecting 3x3 matrices to have only 3 rows...

Comment: @Rook ..... Well I'm not an eye doctor but assume I you can see and could infer that there is a typo. But thank you for pointing that out sir or misses..

Comment: @DavidEdwardsJr. here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab634f0ff4e73aa3 - it's free, public domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are two things that can help you here.

Firstly, `std::getline` can take an optional delimiter parameter. This is handy, because your matrices are delimited by `J`.

```
std::string line;

std::getline(in, line, 'J')
```

This will either leave `line` empty (for the first entry in your file) or with a long string containing a bunch of space-delimited integers. Note that `std::getline` will pull the delimiter out of the stream, but not add it to the string argument, so you don't need to worry about the `J` when it comes to parsing the integer bits.

You can feed that into a `std::stringstream`, and yank out all the integers in a loop like this:

```
std::vector<int> matrix;
std::stringstream ss(line);
int i;

while (ss >> i)
    matrix.push_back(i);
```

and you'll get a nice 1-dimensional vector full of all your numbers. Writing a simple indexing function that can convert between a row,column format that you probably want from a matrix, and the offset format you'll need with a vector is left as an exercise to the reader as it is pretty simple. Don't forget to handle the empty-line situation for the very first `J`!

You can wrap this stuff up in a loop,

```
while (std::getline(in, line)) { /* ... */ }
```

easily enough, and do something like generate a vector of vectors that'll be dead easy to work with later in your application.